# Data type IP in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We are pushing data in ElasticSearch via logstash. The issue is that for the IP address, it is being stored as a string rather as an IP data type. Is it possible to specify it via grok? I have tried the follow code below but it does not seem to work.

```
ip {             match => [ "ip", "IPV4" ]     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping cannot be achieved inside logstash because it is not possible to set complex types inside [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_grok_basics):

> By default all semantics are saved as strings. If you wish to convert
>   a semantic’s data type, for example change a string to an integer then
>   suffix it with the target data type. For example %{NUMBER:num:int}
>   which converts the num semantic from a string to an integer. **Currently
>   the only supported conversions are int and float.**

However, there are [thoughts about that feature](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1859).

For now, you need to specify a custom [elasticsearch template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html). Start with [logstash's default elasticsearch template](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json) and add a line in the properties part:

```
"ip": { "type": "ip"},
```

Set the file path to your `template.json` in the [elasticsearch output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template) of your logstash configuration:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        # Your existing config
        template => "/path/to/your/template.json"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind that templates are applied to new indices only.

Comment: Thanks for your help.